# один ко многим, entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

[image: у меня 2 таблицы customers и orders]

email уникальный

когда я ввожу email и если этот email уже существует я хочу, чтобы ID существующего email-а записывался в таблице orders(CustomerId)

```
   using System;
using System.Linq;
using Project_Geolab;

public class ExistingCustomer 
{
    private readonly string email;
    private readonly string productname;
    private readonly int quantity;

    public ExistingCustomer(string email, string productname, int quantity)
    {

        this.email = email;

        this.productname = productname;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void Existing()
    {
        using(Technic context = new Technic())
        {
            var ExistingEmail = context.Customers.Where(o => o.Email == this.email);
            Order order = new Order()
            {
                ProductName = this.productname,
                Quantity = this.quantity
            };
            context.Orders.Add(order);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}



public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [StringLength(45)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на заказы
    public virtual List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime PurchaseDate { get; set; }

    // Ссылка на покупателя
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: кажется, я уже видел этот вопрос. Вы его пересоздаете что ли?

Comment: нет , просто никто не ответил и я задал вопрос по другому

Comment: ну так вы `Customer` должны сначала из базы получить по емейлу, а потом уже его использовать при создании ордера, а вы что то не то делаете

Comment: А где у Вас `context.SaveChanges()`? Как понять "ID существующего email-а"? У Вас email в отдельной таблице? Из приведённого Вами скриншота мало понятно где какая таблица...

Comment: первая таблица customer вторая orders

Comment: Я через консоль ввожу email  и данные о orders и если этот email которую я ввёл в консоль уже существует в базе тогда в таблице orders должен добавиться данные ,а в таблице customer ничего(email)